# Why is it valid to use squared Euclidean distances in high dimensions in multiple regression?

Tags: soft-question, linear-regression

Euclidean distance is not linear in high dimensions. However, in multiple regression the idea is to minimize square distances from data points to a hyperplane.

Other data analysis techniques have been considered problematic for their reliance on Euclidean distances (nearest neighbors), and dimensionality reduction techniques have been proposed.

Why is this not a problem in multiple regression?

Comment: What does "Euclidean distance is not linear in high dimensions" mean?  I thought the issue was that random points tended to be similar distances apart, but that is not the same thing.

Comment: @Henry The issue I have with these concepts comes about after reading [this Quora post](https://www.quora.com/Why-cant-we-use-Euclidean-distance-as-a-measure-when-dealing-with-high-dimensional-data). I am not sure how to answer the question on your comment.

Comment: @Henry And the Quora post resulted from a search after reading a Twitter post by N Taleb, which is verbatim: "Actually, the Euclidean leads to a yuuuge misrepresentation, bad statistics & psych papers. For 2 d, Eucl= the norm L1 (Abs deviation), so linear. For higher dimensions, it becomes a nonlinear metric: standard deviation is NOT mean abs deviation. See in SCFT."

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using OLS/GLS regression if the data satisfies the underlying assumptions (e.g., likelihood or the actual cost function is that).  It is up to you to check the hypotheses are satisfied before using it, and whether it is the correct language to phrase your problem.  The problem is that people having no clues what they are doing decided that "best approximation" must mean "least square approximation" without actually thinking about it first.

Comment: @user10354138 Certainly. And if you have a predicted (independent variable) that can be say, 'annual income' of 2 million people, and the regressors are a bunch of variables, you can do a multiple regression. No problem. The independent variable is considered just one dimension. But it is one dimension in $\mathbb R^{2\times10^6},$ which to me it high dimensional. Yet, you have to be wary of doing KNN. Why?

Comment: When Taleb said *"For 2 d, Eucl= the norm L1 (Abs deviation), so linear"* I suspect he meant 1D.  Variance is not linear but is still often a useful concept, and the same can be said for ordinary least squares regression (which is linear in one sense but not another): they can help in some situations and mislead in others

Comment: As for N Taleb's comment, in 2d, Eucl is $L_2$, not $L_1$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how regression applies to this question but Euclidean distance is valid in any number of dimensions as shown by the Pythagorean theorem where:
$$A^2+B^2+C^2+\cdots+X^2=Y^2\quad\text{where}\quad X,Y\space\text{are arbitrary variables}$$
For example, we know that $3^2+4^2=5^2$ can be a diagonal on the front of a box. If the depth of the box is $12$, then we can also know that the distance between opposite corners is shown by the equation
$3^2+4^2+12^2=13^2\space$ because the $5^2$ in $(5,12,13)$ calculations can be replaced with $3^2+4^2$.

Likewise, if we have a $4$D box $\quad 3^2+4^2+12^2+84^2=85^2\quad$ because the triples  $\quad (3,4,5)\quad (5,12,13)\quad (13,84,85)\quad$ can all be similarly joined into a quintuple. The process can be reversed for dimensional reduction.
For example $\quad 3^2+4^2+12^2+84^2=\quad 3^2+12.64911064^2+84^2=85$

At least one form of regression works on minimizing distances and the
corner-to-corner distances here are the shortest [straight-line] distance. The example has shown integer solutions but works the same with non-integers such as those found by $\space A=x_1-x_0\quad B=y_1-y_0\quad C=z_1-z_0\quad \cdots $

There are methods of finding missing values if one is unknown and I have been compiling many of these in a paper. If these would be useful, I can probably translate them to your application if I can understand what your application is.

Comment: Great answer. I would like to take you up on your offer... My application is OLS. I can link the clearest explanation available by Professor Strang...

Comment: [Here it is](https://youtu.be/osh80YCg_GM) but instead of the three points there would be many.

Comment: @Numerically illiterate   $\quad$ I graduated from college $42$ years ago so I've forgotten a lot but I will be glad to help if I can. Please email me at the address in my profile with specific questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind offer.

Answer (score 1):

The nice thing about
squared Euclidean distance
is that is the simplest function
that is differentiable,
so you can set the
derivative
(or partial derivatives) to zero
to get an extreme value.

It also has other nice properties
such as easily giving
the minimizer of the distance
of a value to a set of values
is the mean
(i.e.,
minimizing
$\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-a)^2$
with respect to $a$
gives
$a=(1/n)\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$).

Whether this is what you want
is another matter.